# Prototype and jQuery concatenation failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, prototypejs

**EDIT:** I've taken jQuery and prototype libs out of the equation, but the problem still remains.

**Simplified Test Case 1 -** [Without Concatenation](http://www.codenothing.com/dev/js-script-loading/)
The $ function is decalared using window.$ in a.js, and is declared in function notation in b.js. b.js is loaded second, and overwrites a.js $ function

**Simplified Test Case 2 -** [WIth Concatenation](http://www.codenothing.com/dev/js-script-loading/concat.html)
Combined a.js and b.js, with a first, and b second. the function declaration

---

I found something strange when trying to concatenate prototype and jQuery. It seems as though when concatenated, the $ jquery reference doesn't get overwritten by prototype. I've built two test cases to single this out, and it's failing in Chrome8 and FF 3.6.

**Test Case 1 -** [Without Concatenation](http://www.codenothing.com/dev/prototype-jquery-concat/)
jQuery and Prototype are loaded separately with different script tags. jQuery is loaded first, Prototype second.

**Test Case 2 -** [With Concatenation](http://www.codenothing.com/dev/prototype-jquery-concat/concat.html)
jQuery and Prototype are concatenated into a single file, and loaded with a single script tag. jQuery is first in the script, and prototype is added second.

These should act identically, but the second test is throwing errors because the $ function in prototype doesn't overwrite the $ jquery reference.

Did I set these up wrong, or are browsers rendering javascript differently when it's all in the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ function in Prototype is instantiated with a function declaration:

```
function $(element) {
```

Since the Prototype library is not in a closure, the assumed scope is the window. Variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope, so "function $" is declared, and then the $ variable is overwritten by jQuery.

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/psC7s/

Comment: But that doesn't explain how, when loaded in separate script tags, the function declaration does overwrite the jQuery defined one.

Comment: I've got a theory for that one. The two files are both executed in the same scope, but sequentially. If both libraries are in the same file, all global declarations are hoisted to the top, and we see the behavior which we are discussing. If the libraries are in separate files, the hoisting occurs twice, so the jQuery $ declaration happens first, and then the Prototype $ declaration happens when the second file is parsed, overwriting jQuery.

Comment: @Corey: I'm wondering what would happen if you just stick a jQuery.noConflict() call in between the concatenated libraries...

Comment: @draeton: I'm guessing it restores the $ references to it's undefined value, which allows it to be overwritten with the function declaration? - http://www.codenothing.com/dev/prototype-jquery-concat/noconflict.html

Comment: @Corey: It doesn't restore it to `undefined`. It restores it to the prototypejs reference, since prototype referenced `$` *before* any of the jQuery code ran.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes so much more sense. Parser reads in function declarations first, then assignments.

Comment: @Corey: Exactly. You should probably have the `noConflict()` in between them as @draeton suggested. When I stepped through the code before `noConflict()` was added, jQuery had reference to `$` while the prototypejs code was executing. So parts of prototypejs may be broken without that placement. Not sure though.

Comment: Definitely check out this article on hoisting: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 1):

If you call `jQuery.noConflict()` in your code, jQuery will restore the value of `$` to what it was before it grabbed it.

Not sure why it isn't getting overwritten in the first place.

[jQuery keeps a reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L13) to the value of `$` when it loads. [You can see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L379) that the old reference gets restored in the `noConflict()` call.

Comment: Yes, I've added that piece in my project, but I'm more worried as to why the $ var isn't getting overwritten when prototype is loaded second.

Comment: @Corey: Yes, that seems strange. I'm looking at your concatenated file right now.